# Will GetFullPathName work on directory name?

Tags: file, directory

Just wonder if GetFullPathName will work on directory name? Based on the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea, it does not say whether a directory name can be passed as the lpFileName.

Based on my own test, it works. But I want to see official confirmation on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked contains this:

> For more information about file and path names, see [File Names, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

and if you click on the link, you'll see this information

> Note that a directory is simply a file with a special attribute
> designating it as a directory, but otherwise must follow all the same
> naming rules as a regular file. Because the term directory simply
> refers to a special type of file as far as the file system is
> concerned, some reference material will use the general term file to
> encompass both concepts of directories and data files as such.